# Android - How to get position in bindView like in getView?

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-cursoradapter

In `getView()` of `CursorAdapter`, there's a parameter `position` so I can do a checking for that `position`, how can I do the same on `bindView()` it has no `position` parameter in `BindView`.

Currently I'm overriding `newView()`, `bindView()` and `getView()` which I read and heard is bad, either override **`getView()`** OR **`newView()` and `getView()`**.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure your last statement is correct. I think it should read "Either override `getView` or (`newView` and `bindView`)". There is a default implementation of `getView`, that calls `newView` if there isn't a view yet, and `bindView` if the view is being recycled.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this

```
public void bindView(View arg0, Context arg1, Cursor arg2)
{
    int pos = arg2.getPosition();
}
```

Comment: yeah I think this is it.  But why is the cursor.getPosition() in bindView differs from the result of doing the  cursor.getPosition() in newView. More on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557251/android-bindview-and-newview-for-two-view-layout-in-cursoradapter

Answer (score 5):

codeboys answer is correct, cursor.getPosition() will do.
But if someone needs position in the onClick event of listitems subitem, for instance icon inside the listItem, the solution is to put a position as setTag on the icon and retreive it when event occurs:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View vw, Context ctx, final Cursor cursor) {
    /* ...
    *  do your binding 
    */
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) vw.findViewById(R.id.your_icon);
    icon.setTag(cursor.getPosition());   // here you set position on a tag
    icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //  use a tag to get the right position 
            ((MainActivity) context).onIconClick((int)v.getTag());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use "Tag" here because Java supports closures. You can use `pos` captured from the outer context inside your click listener if it is defined inside `bindView` as it is in your example

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int mCount = cursor.getCount();
    //Returns Total count(Rows) in cursor

     int currentPostion= cursor.getPosition();
    //Returns the current position of the cursor in the row set
}
```

Comment: how do i know what view I'm dealing with in bindView if I'm having two layouts in newView.  please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557251/android-bindview-and-newview-for-two-view-layout-in-cursoradapter

Comment: This will not work. ListView recycles rows, so newView only gets called for a subset of the total rows you can scroll view. If you used `getPosition()` in bindView you would effectively track the currently drawn position.

Comment: @CoatedMoose Then how would you do it?

Comment: @mattblang as I said in my previous comment, the default implementation doesn't call `newView` on every list item because it re-uses list items. A reused list item gets called in `bindView`, so you need to use `cursor.getPosition()` in both `bindView` and `newView`.